# How do I dynamically capture in regex two dates from one line of text?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a text that will change weekly:

```
text = "Weekly Comparison, Week 50 October 28 - November 3, 2016 October 30 - November 5, 2015"
```

I'm looking for regex patterns for year 1, and year 2.
(Both will change weekly so I need the formula to capture all months, days, years)

My output should be the following:

```
2015 = November 5, 2015
2016 = November 3, 2016
```

The framework I'm using does not allow for regex capture groups or splits, so I need the formula to be specialized for this type of string.

Thanks!

Comment: [`(\w+\s+\d+,\s*(\d+))`](https://regex101.com/r/eXJwof/1) and use `$2 = $1`

Comment: That works but it captures both dates under the same variable, since it's all coming from one line I would need to somehow split up year 2016 from 2015.  I think maybe looking for another word after 2016 but not capturing that word will make this work

Comment: Please see the link I created demonstrating the regex in use. Note, I added `.*?` to display the result in regex101

Comment: You cannot use re.split()?

Comment: @staten12 I've converted my comments into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

As per my original comments

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/eXJwof/1)

```
(\w+\s+\d+,\s*(\d+))
```

**Note**: The above regex and the regex on regex101 do not match. This is done purposely. Regex101 can only demonstrate the output of substitutions, thus I've prepended `.*?` to the regex in order to properly display the expected output.

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Weekly Comparison, Week 50 October 28 - November 3, 2016 October 30 - November 5, 2015
```

#### Output

```
2016 = November 3, 2016
2015 = November 5, 2015
```

---

### Usage

```
import re
regex = r"(\w+\s+\d+,\s*(\d+))"
str = "Weekly Comparison, Week 50 October 28 - November 3, 2016 October 30 - November 5, 2015"
for (date, year) in re.findall(regex, str):
    print year + ' = ' + date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
text = "Weekly Comparison, Week 50 October 28 - November 3, 2016 October 30 - November 5, 2015"
import re
final_data = sorted(["{} = {}".format(re.findall("\d+$", i)[0], i) for i in re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+\s\d+,\s\d+", text)], key=lambda x:int(re.findall("^\d+", x)[0]))
```

Output:

```
['2015 = November 5, 2015', '2016 = November 3, 2016']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @ctwheels regex:

```
text = "Weekly Comparison, Week 50 October 28 - November 3, 2016 October 30 - November 5, 2015"

import re
result = [(date.split(",")[1].strip(), date) for date in re.findall(r'\w+\s+\d+,\s*\d+', text)]
print(result)

# [('2016', 'November 3, 2016'), ('2015', 'November 5, 2015')]
```